# Using pandas as part of project instead of installing it

Tags: python, pandas, python-wheel

I need to use pandas module for reading a excel file.

I can see that we can install pandas using pip, apt-get , yum etc.,

But I do have a restriction for installing a package.

Whatever the module I am using, I have to keep it in with my project source code instead of installing it.

I did the same for using the beautifulsoup module before.

Once I kept the same in my project source, I will install the same.

So I need to know the way or possibility for using pandas in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a [Virtual Environment](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) using `virtualenv`. The virtual environment will reside in your own user directory without requiring any permissions. You can then install whatever packages you want into the virtual environment, again, with no special permissions.

Comment: Actually I need to port this code to production , so virtualenv can't work, Thing is like I just need to give source code, finally it should work without any module or package installation.

Comment: Why not? We use virtual environments in production all the time.

Comment: I understand, But I need to do without virtualenv